# error: Cannot find setter for field - Room

Tags: android, android-room

I don't really know why I have this error. The code seems pretty straight forward.

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index("clientLocalId")})
.
.

private @PrimaryKey String clientLocalId;


public String getClientLocalId() {
    return clientLocalId;
}

public void setClientLocalId(long idInvoice, String receipt) {
    this.clientLocalId = String.valueOf(idInvoice) + " " + receipt;
}
```

I tried to changed the name in just *client*, restarted and cleared caches, same error.

error: Cannot find setter for field.
private @PrimaryKey String clientLocalId;                          ^

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room is looking for a setter that just takes a single String value. Your method has two.

Change it to the below and use another method to create your concatenated id.

```
public void setClientLocalId(String id) {
    this.clientLocalId = id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it happened because of the second Parameter `receipt` of `clientLocalId`,
remove it or add another setter method,
i recommend you add receipt to your `clientLocalId` out of entity class before inserting in Database